# Add a bar for coordinates zoom-in using QGIS 3.28 and Qgis2Web plugin

Tags: qgis, html, qgis2web

I am using QGIS 3.28.11. I have crated a simple web map using QGIS plugin called - Qgis2Web. I want to modify the HTML file to include a search bar for zooming in by coordinates. The CRS of the project is EPSG:2039.

Can you help me?

***Here is the HTML code:***

<!doctype html>

.ol-geocoder.gcd-gl-container {
                top: 135px!important;
                left: .5em!important;
                width: 2.1em!important;
                height: 2.1em!important;
            }
            /* ... Other existing styles ... */
        
        
            /* Existing styles */
        
        
            /* More existing styles */
        
        
        
            /* Additional existing styles */
        
        
            #map {
                width: 1493px;
                height: 803px;
            }

```
    <!-- Search bar for zooming to coordinates -->
    <div id="search-container" class="ol-control">
        <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter coordinates (e.g., lat, lon)">
        <button id="search-button">Go</button>
    </div>

    <script src="resources/qgis2web_expressions.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/proj4.js"></script>
    <script>proj4.defs('','+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.7343936111111 +lon_0=35.2045169444444 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs');</script>
    <script src="resources/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="resources/horsey.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/ol3-search-layer.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/ol-layerswitcher.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/ol-geocoder.js"></script>
    <script src="layers/23102023_1.js"></script>
    <script src="styles/23102023_1_style.js"></script>
    <script src="./layers/layers.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="./resources/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./resources/qgis2web.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
            const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');

            searchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                const coordinates = searchInput.value.split(',');
                if (coordinates.length === 2) {
                    const lat = parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
                    const lon = parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
                    if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lon)) {
                        map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]));
                        map.getView().setZoom(15); // You can adjust the zoom level as needed.
                    } else {
                        alert('Invalid coordinates. Please enter coordinates in the format: lat, lon');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid coordinates. Please enter coordinates in the format: lat, lon');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should integrate the `ol-ext library` and then use this [functionality](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/search/map.control.searchgps.html) like this:

**At the beginning of your head, AFTER LOADING ol.js**

```html
<!-- viglino ol-ext -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
```

**At the bottom of the body of your html**

```js
// Set the control grid reference
  var search = new ol.control.SearchGPS({
    // target: $('.options').get(0)
  });
  map.addControl(search);

  // Select feature when click on the reference index
  search.on('select', function(e){
    // console.log(e);
    map.getView().animate({
      center:e.search.coordinate,
      zoom: Math.max (map.getView().getZoom(),5)
    });
  });
```

Comment: I appreciate your help very much

Comment: If you think the answer satisfies your question, vote it as the correct answer